# find the maximal number of distinct pairwise commuting involutions on $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, contest-math

> Source: IMC 1996, day 1, problem 3

> The linear operator $A$ on the vector space $V$ is an involution if $A^2 = E$ where $E$ is the identity operator on $V$. Let $\dim V = n < \infty$. Find the maximal number of distinct pairwise commuting involutions on $V$.

I know that every projection has a basis of eigenvectors (which can be the union of a basis of eigenvectors of eigenvalue 0 and a basis of eigenvectors of eigenvalue 1), which is useful for solving part a of the original question. For part b, which is shown in this question, I have several questions about the solution they presented:

Let $\{A_i : i\in I\}$ be a set of commuting diagonalizable operators on $V$ and let $A_1$ be one of these operators. Choose an eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A_1$ and denote $V_\lambda = \{v\in V : A_1 v = \lambda v\}$. $V_\lambda$ is a subspace of $V$ and since $A_1 A_i = A_iA_1$ for $i\in I$ so $V_\lambda$ is invariant under each $A_i$.

> Now if $V_\lambda = V,$ why is $A_1$ either $E$ or $-E$?

Then we can start with another operator $A_i$.

> If $V_\lambda \neq V,$ how can we show by induction on $\dim V$ that there is a common eigenvector for all the $A_i$'s?

> Why does this show that all the $A_i$'s are diagonalizable?

> Why do different diagonal matrices for the $A_i$'s correspond to different $A_i$'s? In other words, one can't find an $A_i$ so that there exists bases $B_1,B_2$ so that the matrix representations $[A_i]_{B_1}$ and $[A_i]_{B_2}$ are diagonal and distinct. I know that similar matrices have the same eigenvalues and the eigenvalues of any diagonal matrix are the elements of the main diagonal, which could be useful. I think this might be some known property of linear transformations, but I'm not sure which one.

Finally, if $|I| = 2^n$, then note that for any basis $B$ for which $[A_i]_B$ is diagonal, $[A_i]_B^2 = I$ from above, and from the change-of-basis formula, $[A_i]_B^2 = [A_i^2]_B = [E]_B,$ which implies that $A_i^2 = E$ because the linear maps agree on a basis. Thus we just need to show that the $A_i$'s are commuting. If the $A_i$'s can be represented as diagonal matrices under the same basis, then this is straightfoward: $[A_i]_B [A_j]_{B} = [A_j]_B [A_i]_B\Rightarrow [A_i A_j]_B = [A_j A_i]_B\Rightarrow A_iA_j = A_j A_i.$ But if not, I'm not sure what to do.

> Perhaps this is what the solution meant by "therefore $\{A_i : i \in I\}$ are simultaneously diagonalizable"?

Comment: Not sure why you mention projections. Projections satisfy $P^2=P$, not $P^2=E$.

Comment: Obligatory remark: as the solution assumes that involutions are diagonalisable, the problem apparently is missing the condition that the characteristic of the field is not $2$.

Comment: You don't quote nor link to the "solution they presented". Just from reading your questions it is clear to me that you are not accurately understanding (and therefore not accurately reporting) what their presented solution is. It would be better if you quote that solution *verbatim*, and then intersperse your questions at the points they arise. (For example, the fact that they have a common eigenvector is not what implies they are are diagonalizable; it is the fact that their square is the identity that implies they are diagonalizable).